# I'm trying to find where there may be a variable out of scope in this code; it's related to Items within a text game

Tags: java

The error occurs in the second fragment. Advice please?

Code for looking at a specific Item

```
private void lookItem(Command command) 
{
    if (!command.hasSecondWord())
    {
        // If there is no second word, we don't know where to look...
        System.out.println("Look where?");
        return;
    }        
    else
    {
        // First check to see if that item is in the room...
        // Need a loop to run through ArrayList and determine yes/no that the item is here
        boolean presentInRoom = false;
        for (int i=0; i<currentRoom.inventory.size(); i++)
        {
            if (currentRoom.inventory.get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(command.getSecondWord()) == true)
            {
                presentInRoom = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        // If the item was present in the room's ArrayList, read or look at it
        if (presentInRoom == true)
        {
            System.out.println ("You look at" );
        }

        // If the item was not present in the room's ArrayList print an error message
        if (presentInRoom == false)
        {
            System.out.println( "isn't here!");
        }
    }
}
```

Code for taking a specific item

```
private void takeItem(Command command)
{
    if (!command.hasSecondWord())
    {
        // if there is no second word, we don't know what to take...
        System.out.println("Take what?");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        // First check to see if that item is in the room...
        // Need a loop to run through ArrayList and determine yes/no that the item is here
        boolean presentInRoom = false;
        for (int i=0; i<currentRoom.inventory.size(); i++)
        {
            if (currentRoom.inventory.get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(command.getSecondWord()) == true)
            {
                presentInRoom = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // If the item was present in the room's ArrayList, add it to our own belongings (add
    // to our own ArrayList, and delete from the ArrayList for this room
    if (presentInRoom == true)
    {
        belongings.add(i);
        inventory.remove(i);
        System.out.println("You take" );
    }

    // If the item was not present in the room's ArrayList print an error message
    if (presentInRoom == false)
    {
        System.out.println("isn't here!");
    }
}
```

The second piece of code flags up

> cannot find symbol - variable presentInRoom

when I try compiling. I'd also like to know how to specify an Item in println.

Comment: You should declare `boolean presentInRoom` above the first `if`

Answer (score 1):

Declare `presentInRoom` at the beginning of your method and you should be fine (also added an `itemFound` string for the last system out):

```
private void takeItem(Command command)
{
    boolean presentInRoom = false;
    String itemFound = "";
    Integer itemId = null;
    if(!command.hasSecondWord())
    {
        // if there is no second word, we don't know what to take...
        System.out.println("Take what?");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        // First check to see if that item is in the room...
        // Need a loop to run through ArrayList and determine yes/no that the item is here

        for (int i=0; i<currentRoom.inventory.size(); i++)
        {
            if (currentRoom.inventory.get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(command.getSecondWord()) == true)
            {
                presentInRoom = true;
                itemFound = currentRoom.inventory.get(i).getName();
                itemId = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // If the item was present in the room's ArrayList, add it to our own belongings (add
    // to our own ArrayList, and delete from the ArrayList for this room
    if (presentInRoom == true)
    {
         belongings.add(itemId);
         inventory.remove(itemId);
         System.out.println("You take "+itemFound);
    }

    // If the item was not present in the room's ArrayList print an error message
    if (presentInRoom == false)
    {
        System.out.println("isn't here!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) I have another question. I've got the inventory ArrayList to and want items to be removed from it to a belongings ArrayList with the following code. However, compiling this results in the error message "cannot find symbol - variable i".

if (presentInRoom == true)
        {
            inventory.remove(i);
            belongings.add(i);
            System.out.println("You take"+itemFound);
            }

Comment: Sorry I've missed that part: "i" is a valid variable only INSIDE your loop, outside the for cycle your JVM cannot find that symbol. I'm gonna edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks again. That produces an error of "incompatible types" at the 'getName' part of line itemFound = currentRoom.inventory.get(i).getName();

For clarity, that is set in the Item class with below code.

public class Item 
{
    private String name; // stores details for items.

    public Item(String name) 
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}

Comment: Actually, that seems OK now but I'm getting "cannot find symbol - variable inventory" as linked to code in my first comment.

Comment: Well, I thought your inventory, belongings and currentRoom variables were present at class level. You're always doing the same mistake: you have to declare/set at the start of the method/class/conditional block the variables you need.